# Adapt MySQL query to JDatabase query

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am trying to execute a query through Joomla 2.5.

By using the following MySQL query, it performs correctly:

`$query = "REPLACE INTO fa_usr (id, date_time, usr, clu) SELECT NULL, NOW(), " . $usr . ", " . $clu . " FROM DUAL WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fa_use_clu WHERE usr=" . $usr . " AND clu=" . $clu . ") < 1";`

Now, as I'm trying to use JDatabaseQuery methods, how the above mentioned query could be transformed correctly?

I have checked [this link](http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase), which is from the official documentation, but seems I cannot find an appropriate solution.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Does it need to be transformed in the first place?

Comment: It's mostly of educational interest, as I keep learning. Even though, I want the query to be flexible, just in case the client will decide to switch to another server with a different database system... Or it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Ah, I see, they have a full-blown database layer now. Not sure whether that layer can handle this complex syntax

Comment: As far as I can see in the source code to this point, `replace` isn't supported using the JDatabaseQuery methods. It seems that the core query types it does support are insert, update, delete and select. My only other advice is to handle subqueries as their own query object and then pass that subquery object with the conditional concated to the parent's where function on the parent query object (`$query->where((string)$subquery . ' < 1');`).

Comment: Is this question more about REPLACE INTO or about JDatabaseQuery as a whole?  Since REPLACE INTO isn't supported if you want database agnostic support for drivers for which it requires differing syntaxes. In that case I personally would usually either write the method and send a PR with it or look around SO or elsewhere for questions like "how do you do this mysql statement in database x" and try to avoid using the mysql specific  statement. Or do you want to know how to do subqueries?

Comment: Hello everyone and thank you for your input. I will follow @DavidFritsch ' s suggestion. Thanks a lot!